# Model selection/multi-level model with metafor package

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I'm attempting to conduct both a model selection and multilevel model analysis with the metafor package. Unfortunately, the data I am working with does not have any control group, only a response rate(i.e. proportion) of individuals that reacted favorably to a medical treatment.

How can I conduct a multilevel analysis without a control group? Is it possible?

I appreciate any information you can provide me with.

Answer (score 3):

Meta-analysis of non-comparative studies does not raise any serious statistical issues. You will need to decide whether you want to transform the proportions (see the documentation for `escalc` for some possibilities). Then you proceed as normal using your preferred analysis function (I assume `rma.mv`).

Of course since these are observational studies the summary is subject to the same issues as a single study for interpretation and heterogeneity is to be expected but that is a problem highlighted by the meta-analysis but not caused by it.

Comment: For the escalc function, I need parameters that would come from a 2x2 contingency table. How would I do this if I only have those who reacted favorably to a treatment and those who didn't?

Comment: The ``escalc()`` function isn't just for 2x2 table data. Please read ``help(escalc)``.

Comment: You could also read http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206431/odds-ratio-meta-analysis-with-no-control-group